# how to call one application from another in android

Tags: android

I am doing one application for that I need to call " com.android.settings.DeviceAdminAdd" from my application. how to call this class in my app. My code is like this but it is not working

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setClassName("com.android.settings", "com.android.settings.DeviceAdminAdd");
startActivity(intent);
```

thx in advance

Comment: What do you mean by "it is not working"? Does it give an error?

Comment: No error. but i am not able to launch setting/DeviceAdminAdd activity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `setClassName` use `setComponent`, as below

```
Intent intentDeviceTest = new Intent("android.intent.action.MAIN");  
intentDeviceTest.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.intent.service",
                                 "com.intent.service.InentServiceDemoActivity"));
startActivity(intentDeviceTest);
```

Answer (score 1):

Set DeviceAdminAdd activity property exported=true in manifest file. and call as follows:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(com.android.settings.this, com.android.settings.DeviceAdminAdd.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try...

```
Intent intent = new Intent(DevicePolicyManager.ACTION_ADD_DEVICE_ADMIN);
startActivity(intent);
```

From the docs...

[DevicePolicyManager.ACTION_ADD_DEVICE_ADMIN](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/admin/DevicePolicyManager.html#ACTION_ADD_DEVICE_ADMIN)

Answer (score 1):

i've tried this code now and it works , it opens the `AddAccount Activity` :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_ADD_ACCOUNT);
        startActivity(intent);
```

Regards , 
Houcine

Comment: no permission needed ,i've tried it right now and it works for me

Comment: you should import the Settings from : android.provider

Answer (score 0):

Please try this,

```
Intent LaunchIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.package.address");
startActivity( LaunchIntent );
```

Comment: Using this code, launches multiple instances of the application.I have tried using launch mode to single instance in the startup activity of the application but still the applications opens up in multiple instances.How can i solve this.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead(note the 1st line is different):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
intent.setClassName("com.android.settings", "com.android.settings.DeviceAdminAdd");
startActivity(intent);
```

If it doesn't work for some reason another (better) option is to use the PackageManager to get an Intent for the package:

```
PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
Intent intent = pm.getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.android.settings");
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Window already focused, ignoring focus gain of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@405f2dd0. getting this message in logcat

Answer (score 0):

you can read this code

```
public class CurrentActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {       
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        Intent intent=new Intent(this,TargetActivityName.class);       
        this.startActivity(intent);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

All the answer are correct. You should however **NEVER** target an application by package name **UNLESS** it is your application. This will cause problems with future releases if you follow this pattern.